# what does this interface declaration mean in java?

Tags: java, generics, interface

It might be a noob question but I am learning java and I came across an interface which had its definition like :

`public interface MyClass <T extends Comparable<T>>`

Can someone please explain what does it mean? I mean what kind of interface is created.

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the generic type argument must implement the `Comparable` interface.

When specifying `<T extends Comparable<T>>` you can use e.g. Collections.sort in this interface on type `T`. Without `extends` you can not guarantee that `T` is comparable.

Numbers and String are e.g. comparable and implement the `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

The interface takes a type `T` which is `Comparable` with other `T`.

The interface is much the same only its generic type is constrained.

Answer (score 0):

It means that T must implement Comparable over the same object.

for example

```
public interface MyClass <T extends Comparable<T>>
```

en then you can use as follow

```
public class MyImpl implements MyClass<String>
```

It is valid because String implements Comparable. But the following sentence is not valid because MyNewImpl is not implementing Comparable.

```
public class MyNewImpl {}    
public class MyImplTwo implements MyClass<MyNewImpl>
```

Regards
Ignacio